# How to load iframe in background?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to silently load an iframe in the background using pure JavaScript

Here is my code:

```
function prepareFrame(URL) {
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.src = URL;
    ifrm.style.width = "0px";
    ifrm.style.height = "0px";
    ifrm.style.border = "None";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

For some reason the iframe isn't loading

Thanks for the help

Comment: And? What's the problem?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What errors in the console do you get?

Comment: Just check in your networks tab as soon as you append it to `<body>` you should see a request being fired.But why are u using `body[0]` and getbytagname shouldn't it be just `document.body.appendChild(ifrm);` ?

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console

Comment: Is the answer helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082681/how-to-load-iframe-in-background/41082791#41082791

Answer (score 0):

It's not displaying because you set the `width` and the `height` attributes to `0px`. Remove that, and it should work. I think you meant a different property.

Comment: It has to be silent, thats why I am making it hidden

Comment: Perhaps you can use `ifrm.style.display = "none";` and test if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It will help you. for visibility purpose i changed the width and height to 100px you can define your value in that.

if you want to make the frame invisible then you need to give `ifrm.style.visibility = "hidden";`

```js
function prepareFrame(URL) {
  var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
  ifrm.src = URL;
  ifrm.style.width = "100px";
  ifrm.style.height = "100px";
  ifrm.style.border = "None";
  ifrm.style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="prepareFrame('http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp')">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: couldnt it be `ifrm.style.display = "none";`?

Comment: if u use this iframe will not be loaded even in hidden,if u use ifrm.style.visibility ='hidden' then you can find iframe in hidden form

Comment: And how would you test that?

Comment: first set ifrm.style.visibility ='hidden' now the iframe is in hidden mode, then  set ifrm.style.visibility ='visible' now iframe will  be visible to you. you can test this by using browser's inspect element.

Comment: yes, but the OP requested to silently **load** the iframe, not just put it there. If you did it using `display: none;` and then `display: block;`, it should also end in the same result.

Comment: what is mean by OP?

Comment: The OP requested to load the iframe _while it is hidden_, so that when it is shown, it is already loaded.

Comment: I believe that only when it is visible does it load. That is the OP's problem.